# sharepoint 2013 itemupdated with argumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: sharepoint-2013, event-receiver

I'm facing an issue with sharepoint 2013 and an event receiver itemupdated. In this event, i move item to an other library with

```
properties.ListItem.File.MoveTo(Url + "/" + properties.ListItem.File.Name);
```

I try too with this at begining but without success

```
this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
```

It goes correctly till the correct library but i receive an error sharepoint with a correlationID

Regarding log with correlationID , i get an error

```
Unexpected  System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
```

i tested synchronous or not

It seems that sharepoint try to reload the form edit but the item has moved to an other library

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think, to make it work, you should retrieve new object from the list and perform the operation there.

something like

```
var item = properties.List.GetItemByID(properties.ListItemId);
item.File.MoveTo(Url + "/" + item.File.Name);
```

`SPItemEventProperties` doesn't like when you're messing with his internal elements (dispose, move, delete etc.)